# ¿Cómo puedo definir varios segmentos de una matriz numpy basada en pares de índices de inicio / finalización sin iterar?

Tags: numpy

Tengo dos matrices que representan los índices de inicio y longitud (o podría ser inicio y fin) en esta matriz que identifican secuencias de enteros que necesito procesar. Las secuencias son de longitud variable.

```
x=numpy.array([2,3,5,7,9,12,15,21,27,101, 250]) # Puede tener una longitud de millones
starts=numpy.array([2,7]) # Puede tener longitudes de miles
ends=numpy.array([5,9])

# required output is x[2:5],x[7:9] in flat 1D array 
# [5,7,9,12,21,27,101]
```

Puedo hacer esto fácilmente con for loops, pero la aplicación es sensible al rendimiento, así que estoy buscando una manera de hacerlo sin el iterador de Python.

¡Cualquier ayuda será recibida con gratitud!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Propuesta #1**

Un enfoque vectorizado sería el enmascaramiento creado con la transmisión:

```
In [16]: r = np.arange(len(x))

In [18]: x[((r>=starts[:,None]) & (r<ends[:,None])).any(0)]
Out[18]: array([ 5,  7,  9, 21, 27])
```

**Propuesta #2**

Otra forma vectorizada sería crear rampas de 1s y 0s con ***cumsum*** (debería ser mejor con muchos pares de inicio y fin), así:

```
idx = np.zeros(len(x),dtype=int)
idx[starts] = 1
idx[ends[ends<len(x)]] = -1
out = x[idx.cumsum().astype(bool)]
```

**Propuesta #3**

Otro basado en bucles para lograr la eficiencia de la memoria, podría ser mejor con muchas entradas en los pares de inicio y fin:

```
mask = np.zeros(len(x),dtype=bool)
for (i,j) in zip(starts,ends):
    mask[i:j] = True
out = x[mask]
```

**Propuesta #4**

Para completar, aquí hay otro con un bucle para seleccionar sectores y luego asignarlos a una matriz inicializada y debería ser bueno en los sectores que se seleccionarán de una matriz grande

```
lens = ends-starts
out = np.empty(lens.sum(),dtype=x.dtype)
start = 0
for (i,j,l) in zip(starts,ends,lens):
    out[start:start+l] = x[i:j]
    start += l
```

Si las iteraciones son muchas, existe una optimización menor posible para reducir el cálculo por iteración:

```
lens = ends-starts
lims = np.r_[0,lens].cumsum()
out = np.empty(lims[-1],dtype=x.dtype)
for (i,j,s,t) in zip(starts,ends,lims[:-1],lims[1:]):
    out[s:t] = x[i:j]
```